# write better code instead of 2 for loops

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have 2 for loops and I want to make it better like list comprehension or lambda or else.
how can i achieve the same?

for example :

```
filename = ['a.txt', 'b.txt', 'c.txt']
for files in filename:
    for f in glob.glob(os.path.join(source_path, files)):
        print f
        ... some processing...
```

Comment: I'd recommend first to ensure you really need that. For example, Google Python style guide suggests that your code is fine as it (here's a part about [list comprehensions](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html?showone=List_Comprehensions#List_Comprehensions), lambda functions are below).

Answer (score 27):

Your code is perfectly fine as it is. You can only make it less legible by introducing unnecessary complex constructs.

Comment: @thebjom: can you explain which unnecessary complex constructs?

Comment: Neither list comprehensions nor lambdas will improve the clarity of that code, hence they're only adding complexity. There are, of course situations where they can make things clearer, but this isn't one of those times.

Comment: +1. And, Pythonic == English. Sometimes you have no choice but writing using 2, 3, or even 4 nested loops because it's hard to use comprehension or lambda. And bugging with style can take you forever to debug and write documentation.

Comment: @CppLearner I disagree on 4 nested loops, *usually* if you find yourself in need of 4 nested loop, it is a good place to introduce a function and refactor. However, 2 nested loops used like in this case seems perfectly fine.

Answer (score 4):

You can compress the two `for` loops into a single [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions)*, with a new `for` loop to extract the file names from it.

```
for f in (f_ for files in filename
             for f_ in glob.glob(os.path.join(source_path, files))):
    print f
    # ...
```

As the other answer said, this is ***not*** better, this is ***worse*** and you ***shouldn't*** use it (I'm not sure that's enough emphasis!). It is far harder to understand what is going on, and probably has little performance benefit (in fact, the extra layers of indirection mean it is likely to be slower).

(* basically equivalent to a list comprehension, but better in situations like this.)

Answer (score 4):

I would do it like below. The reason being that now you can separate your search pattern formation, searching and file prosessing. It is easier to expand if they are unrelated.

If your system is slightly exotic (e.g. distributed network drive), the line with both glob and os.path.join is a nasty line. Although as others have mentioned, two loops is perfectly ok.

```
filename = ['a.txt', 'b.txt', 'c.txt']

searchPatterns = [os.path.join(source_path, files) for files in filename]

searchResults = [glob.glob(pattern) for pattern in searchPatterns]

fileListFlat = sum(searchResults,[])

for file in fileListFlat:
    print file
```

Answer (score 2):

Long expression is hard to read when you have to scan to right and round back. it is even worse when there are many local variables, lambdas and comprehensions, merely being separated by parens and commas, in few lines. Use them only if your code does not get longer and more complex.
For you case, I prefer to extract `find` as a tradeoff. But just as the top answer said, your code is fine enough.

```
from itertools import chain

find = lambda p: glob.glob(os.path.join(source_path, p))
for file in chain(map(find, filename)):
    """
    =) I like one-level indentation here.
    =( I don't know which file pattern is used currently,
       unless I use longer expression...
    """
```